# Build Automation for CodePro AnalytiX

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, code-analysis, codepro

Does Google CodePro AnalytiX have Ant/Gradle tasks that are publicly available? It looks like Google bought CodePro AnalytiX and turned it into an Eclipse-only tool.

Searching the CodePro AnalytiX web pages it is obvious that there were defined Ant tasks for the project at one time (deployed collectively as **CodePro AnalytiX Server**), but that seems too be a dead project (and one I couldn't find).

I really, really like CodePro AnalytiX but it would be absolutely invaluable if there was a way to run it as part of our CI build (which is Ant-based, and soon, will be Gradle-based). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code Pro ships withs ant tasks, see => https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/ant/enhancements  CodePro is part of our build workflow, you need to run Eclipse headless

Comment: see also => https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/ant/headless